# "kill %{job id}" vs "kill {job pid}"

Tags: job-control, jobs

I'm working with some `tail -f path/to/my/log/file | grep pattern&` and I need to kill the process as quick as possible.
With classic `kill {tail PID}`, tail still displays its buffer and it takes around 12 second (on my setup) to get tail completely silent.

However, it's much faster when I kill it with `kill %{job id}` (slightly more than a second).

How is it different to call `kill {tail PID}` and `kill %{job id}`?

Some samples :

```
01/09/2021 15:45:29:670:kill {tail PID}
...
01/09/2021 15:45:39:232: {some log}
01/09/2021 15:45:39:232: {some log}
01/09/2021 15:45:39:232: {last log line}  
takes around 10 seconds to fully shutdown
```

with kill %{job id} :

```
01/09/2021 10:56:57:793 -> (COM12<):kill %{tail job ID}
...
01/09/2021 10:56:58:966 -> (COM12>):[root@my_board ~]# 
takes 1 sec to fully shutdown
```

Comment: Sorry. The question is what is the difference between kill and killall? If yes, both of them just a wrapper to the kill system call. When the system is busy, poor killall may much slower than kill, because it's needed to read the running process list.

Comment: I've tried both killall and kill <PID job 1>;kill <PID job 2> and it takes approximatively the same time. It looks like if I use the job ID (kill %<job ID 1>;kill %<job ID 2>) the full termination is quicker. Why is `kill %<job ID>` faster than `kill <job PID>` ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. PID : (process id). What about job id?

Comment: the `jobs` command returns the background jobs with their job ID [like presented here](https://geek-university.com/linux/jobs-command/)

Comment: You can kill background jobs by specifying their job ID with `kill %<job ID>`.   
My question is : In my case, killing a job using its job ID is much faster than killing it using its PID and I'm wondering why

Comment: Ok, I give up. I don't know what do you _exactly_ do. I started some tail in background, but I give up now.

Comment: @K-att- If you start a command in background, you will get a line like this in output from the shell (at least if you are using bash): `[1] 9322`. The first number, in square brackets, is the **job ID** of the background process, the second number is it's **PID**. You can kill that process using either `kill PID` or `kill %job-ID`. The OP asks why the latter is faster, which is really strange. I have never seen such behaviour.

Comment: I use `tail -f /var/log/messages` which spam my console, if you want to try @raj

Comment: One job but two process. 
3368376 pts/6    S      0:00 tail -f /var/log/mintupdate.log
3368377 pts/6    S      0:00 grep --color=auto ez
tail -f /var/log/mintupdate.log|grep ez&
[6] 3368377
When you kill the job, you kill the tail and also kill the grep.
If you kill the grep just, it's different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you kill the job with kill %6, you kill the tail and kill grep too.

```
tail -f /var/log/mintupdate.log|grep ez&
[6] 3368377
```

If you kill 3368377, you kill just the grep process.

```
3368376 pts/6    S      0:00 tail -f /var/log/mintupdate.log
3368377 pts/6    S      0:00 grep --color=auto ez
```

Of course it caused to kill the tail -f too....

Comment: This is a good observation, but it doesn’t explain why the output continues in the first case (`tail`’s output goes through `grep`, so once `grep` is killed there’s no more output).

Comment: Pipe is broken, process terminate I think. Until not. I don't know why (and I don't want to strace the tail process).

Comment: Yes, when a pipe is broken, the next time the writer attempts to write, it is terminated (`SIGPIPE`).

Comment: I don't know why continues the output, sorry ..... (I thought the problem is the time...)

Comment: Easy to check. If kill PID PID-1 (kill 3368376 3368377 ) and kill %<job id> (kill %6) are same, the problem solved.

Comment: When I tried, the PID returned is the PID of the tail, shouldn't the grep finish right away if the tail is dead ?

Comment: It's exciting. For me returned the grep PID....

Comment: I'm working on busybox, I think this is the reason I have a different behavior. I'm trying on Ubuntu     
Edit : I'm stil having tail's PID on Ubuntu, what is your system ?

Comment: Mint. Anyway. If you start two process, and kill just one, you must wait until the pipe break. When you kill the job, you kill whole processes.

Comment: The buffer of tail that is still displayed during ~10 seconds in my sample is still filtered by grep so I don't think grep is immediately shut down. I've tried different signals to shutdown the jobs (with ID or PID) and it does not help.  
It looks like even grep empties its buffer before really getting shut down

Comment: Well sorry but this answer doesn't explain the observed behavior (concerning the bounty) but it is interesting that the `%` may kill multiple PIDs

Comment: I checked it. https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/master/builtins/kill.def handle the %option in the bash builtin kill command. Useful:  https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigprocmask.2.html 
#define BLOCK_SIGNAL(sig, nvar, ovar) \
do { \
  sigemptyset (&nvar); \
  sigaddset (&nvar, sig); \
  sigemptyset (&ovar); \
  sigprocmask (SIG_BLOCK, &nvar, &ovar); \
} while (0)